# React-Native: TransformError with processing babel-preset-react-native/index.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]
Transform Error when running using command "react-native run-ios" it does not proceed to the welcome screen because of this error

Comment: Try deleting node_modules folder, then run command npm install and then run the project

Comment: @ParasWatts Hi, I tried deleting node_modules folder, doing npm install and then running. It still gives me the TransformError about the babel-preser-react-native

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: That's the content of babel-preset-react-native/index.js

'use strict';

module.exports = require('./configs/main');

I'm new to react-native

Comment: you can try deleting .babelrc file or downgrading babel might work.

Comment: After deleting .babelrc what do I do? And how do I downgrade the babel?

Comment: Try running the project after deleting .babelrc

Comment: @ParasWatts Thanks for the help, deleting the .babelrc file worked for me.

Comment: No Problem ,Happy to help :)

Answer (score 9):

Install `babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0` and run the project.

In current project, do this...

`yarn remove babel-preset-react-native` 
`yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0`

This worked for me, I hope it will for you too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It helps me a lot and reduces the time required to deep dive into issue.

Comment: this worked for me as well. Had the same error. You would think they would patch this up already.